# Servlet 3.0 + JSTL + Struts 2 + Tiles 2 issues

Tags: java, servlets, jstl, tiles

Are there any known issues using JSTL in a Servlet 3.0, Struts 2 and Tiles 2 application?

Consider the following snippet:

```
<tiles:useAttribute id="list" name="importCss" classname="java.util.List" />
<c:forEach var="item" items="${list}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${item}.css" media="all"/>
</c:forEach>
```

This would result in a list of CSS links being generated and works fine as long as our web.xml defines the application to be a Servlet 2.4 application.

However, when that is changed to use Servlet 3.0, we get the following error when accessing a page:

```
JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \
JBWEB000088: The requested resource (/application/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/${item}) is not available
```

That would mean that in `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${item}.css" media="all"/>` the expression `${item}` doesn't get resolved, so I assume that either using expressions or JSTL has changed from Servlet 2.4 to 3.0 or theres a library/configuration issue.

Any ideas or suggestions how to resolve that problem?

Working configuration:

- JBoss 7.2.0
- Struts 2.3.16.x
- Tiles 2.2.2
- JSTL 1.2
- Servlet/WebApp 2.4

Broken configuration:

- JBoss 7.2.0
- Struts 2.3.16.x
- Tiles 2.2.2
- JSTL 1.2
- Servlet/WebApp 3.0  (the only thing that has changed)

Additional info as requested: It seems to work on windows (no errors so far with both Servlet 2.4 and 3.0) but not on Linux (2.4 works, 3.0 doesn't).

As requested, here's the head of our web.xml for Servlet 3.0:

```
<web-app
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  id="Webapp_ID" version="3.0">
```

**UPDATE:**

Further tests seem to hint at the packaging, i.e. when the application is being deployed as a packaged ear file, it doesn't work - neither on Windows nor on Linux - while deploying the application as an exploded ear it works at least on Windows.

**UPDATE 2 [Solution]:**

It turned out that when our build process contained a JSP precompilation task when building the packaged application (the application had been migrated from JBoss 4.2.3 to 7.2.0). JBoss didn't complain about the precompiled JSPs thus far but it seems that precompiling JSPs is neither needed nor supported by JBoss 6+ (https://community.jboss.org/message/735536) and our JspC task used the old Tomcat 5 JspC implementation which naturally doesn't support Servlet 3.0.

Comment: What is your OS? Windows or Linux? Please specify it too. And are you sure your web.xml file <web-app version:"3.0">

Comment: @Erhun yes I'm sure, I can post the relevant part tomorrow. I'll add the OS as well.

Answer (score 1):

It should be permission issue, if it works on Windows and not in Linux be sure you have the permissions to read WEB-INF/lib(chmod) or where is JSTL jars.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the permissions, since we're deploying a single packaged ear which contains the JSTL jars and with Servlet 2.4 there seem to be no permission problems.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code it working..

```
<tiles:importAttribute name="css" />
<!-- Css of specific jsp -->
<c:forEach items="${css}" var="cssfile">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${cssfile}">
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, I'd guess that this code (being similar to mine) wouldn't have worked as well, since as I stated in my second update the real issue was elsewhere. :)